# Get boundaries (position) of canvas drawn context lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a little testing thing for physics. I have drawn a circle with lines using canvas and context:

```
function drawAngles () {
    var d = 50; //start line at (10, 20), move 50px away at angle of 30 degrees
    var angle = 80 * Math.PI/180;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(300,0);
    ctx.lineTo(300,600); //x, y
    ctx.moveTo(0,300);
    ctx.lineTo(600,300);
    ctx.arc(300,300,300,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

I want to somehow get the curved boundaries of the circle so I can tell if the ball element has collided.

If I'm testing boundaries on a typical `div`, I can just do this:

```
var divCoords= $(".boundingBoxDiv").position();
var top = divCoords.top;
etc...
```

How do I do this with context lines?

Here's an image... the ball should bounce off of the circle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/P7S36/)**

This is pretty easy to accomplish, in a radius based collision you just check the distance if the distance is closer than the radius the objects have collided. In this instance we need to do the opposite, if the objects distance is *greater* than the boundary radius we need to change the angle to keep the objects in.

So first we need to identify our boundary center points, and boundary radius,

```
var boundaryRadius = 300,
    boundaryX = 300,
    boundaryY = 300;
```

Later on in the `ball.update` method I check against these values.

```
    var dx = boundaryX - this.x,
        dy = boundaryY - this.y
```

We need to get the distance from our ball and the boundaries center point.

```
        dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

Now we need to get the velocity based on our current angle

```
    this.radians = this.angle * Math.PI/ 180;
    this.velX = Math.cos(this.radians) * this.speed;
    this.velY = Math.sin(this.radians) * this.speed;
```

Next we check if we are still inside of the boundaries. In this instance if our distance is less than 300 - our own radius (which is 10) so 290, then keep moving.

```
    if (dist < boundaryRadius-this.radius) {
        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;
```

Else if our distance is *greater* than 290, we need to first move back a bit so we aren't colliding, then we just change our heading angle. You can do this in much fancier ways to actual calculate where you should bounce to, in this example I just make it the opposite angle with a tad bit of randomness.

```
    } else {
        this.x -= this.velX;
        this.y -= this.velY;
        this.angle += 180+Math.random()*45;
    }
```

[image: fiddle screenshot]

Code in its entirety.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 600,
    height = 600;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var boundaryRadius = 300,
    boundaryX = 300,
    boundaryY = 300;

var Ball = function (x, y, speed) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.radius = 10;
    this.speed = speed || 10;
    this.color = "rgb(255,0,0)";
    this.angle = Math.random() * 360;
    this.radians = this.angle * Math.PI/ 180;
    this.velX = 0;
    this.velY = 0;
}

Ball.prototype.update = function () {
    var dx = boundaryX - this.x,
        dy = boundaryY - this.y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    this.radians = this.angle * Math.PI/ 180;
    this.velX = Math.cos(this.radians) * this.speed;
    this.velY = Math.sin(this.radians) * this.speed;

    // check if we are still inside of our boundary.
    if (dist < boundaryRadius-this.radius) {
        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;
    } else {
        // collision, step back and choose an opposite angle with a bit of randomness.
        this.x -= this.velX;
        this.y -= this.velY;
        this.angle += 180+Math.random()*45;
    }
};

Ball.prototype.render = function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    // draw our circle with x and y being the center
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
    ctx.lineTo(this.px, this.py);
    ctx.closePath();
};

var balls = [],
    ballNum = 10;

for(var i = 0; i < ballNum; i++){
    balls.push(new Ball(boundaryX + Math.random()*30, boundaryY + Math.random() * 30,  5 + Math.random()*15));
}


function drawAngles() {
    var d = 50; //start line at (10, 20), move 50px away at angle of 30 degrees
    var angle = 80 * Math.PI / 180;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(300, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(300, 600); //x, y
    ctx.moveTo(0, 300);
    ctx.lineTo(600, 300);
    ctx.arc(boundaryX, boundaryY, boundaryRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.stroke();
}


function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    drawAngles();

    balls.forEach(function(e){
        e.update();
        e.render();
    });

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into ray casting? Also a neat trick for collision detection is to create a new hidden canvas used for collision detection only. You can then draw the circle on to it using only black and white. If the canvas is filled black with a white circle on it you can test collisions by checking the color of a specific pixel at point x. If point x is black the object has collided, if not it hasn't.

Comment: I do like using the 2nd method for collision detection, and have used it a few times however I generally think its best used when the area you are checking against is odd shaped, with that method you do lose a bit of precision as well. In the OP's case, checking distance from the center is a lot easier and less overhead without needing another canvas.